# How many digits does $C(n)$ have?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, decimal-expansion

Here :

[Are there prime numbers $C(n)$ or $RC(n)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374537/are-there-prime-numbers-cn-or-rcn)

I defined the "crazy-numbers" and the "reversed-crazy-numbers". The number of digits of $C(n)$ is the same as the number of digits of $RC(n)$.

> But how many digits does $C(n)$ have ? Is there a general formula ?

For $1\le n\le 9$, $C(n)$ has $$\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\binom{n+1}{2}$$ digits. This is easy because the number of digits is just  $1+\cdots+n$

For $10\le n\le 99$, $C(n)$ has $$n(n+1)-45$$ digits. This time the number of digits is $45$ (number of digits of $C(9)$) plus $2(10+\cdots+n)$, so we have $n(n+1)-9\cdot 10+45=n(n+1)-45$

For $100\le n\le 999$ , $C(n)$ has $$9855+3\cdot(100+\cdots +n)$$

digits. A pattern apparantly emerges , but I have no idea how I can find a universal formula for every $n$, if there actually is one.

Comment: what are the sums of digits like ?

Comment: For $1\le n\le 9$, the digit sum is $$1+\cdots+n^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$ No idea, whether we have a pattern for larger $n$

Comment: well that may tell you when they divide by 3 etc. ( and all primes above 3 are of one of two remainders when dividing by 6.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a formula : If $s$ is the number of digits of $n$, the number $c(n)$ has $$\frac{99n(n+1)s-(10^s-10)(10^s-1)}{198}$$ digits. With the help of mathworld I determined the formula $$c(10^n-1)=\frac{(10^n-1)(99\cdot 10^nn-10^n+10)}{198}$$ and the rest was relatively easy.

Comment: it seems that this formula does not cover all integers ?!

Comment: The above formula covers all positive integers.

Comment: so if i want to find the number of the digits for, say $C(7911)$ , do i plug $7911$ into your formula ? or what ?

Comment: We have $s=4$ (since $7911$ has $4$ digits) and $n=7911$. Plug it in the above formula.

Comment: very nice !, Thank you