# A conjecture about numbers of the form $10^{m}(2^{k}−1)+2^{k-1}−1$, where $m$ is the number of decimal digits of $ 2^{k-1}$.

Tags: number-theory, integers

**Question**

> Numbers $n$ of the form $10^{m}(2^{k}−1)+2^{k-1}−1$, where $m$ is the number of decimal digits of $ 2^{k-1}$. For example:
>
> - $k=1$ then $n=10$.
> - $k=2$ then $n=31$.
> - $k=3$ then  $n=73$.
> - $k=4$ then $n=157.$

Conjecture:

the number $(2^k-1)\cdot 10^m+2^{k-1}-1$ where $m$ is the number of decimal digits of $2^{k-1}$ is never prime when it is of the form $7s+6$, that is when it is congruent to $6$ $\pmod 7$. Examples: $n=1023511$ ($k=10$)$\equiv 6 \pmod 7$ and thus it is composite $(1023511=19\times103\times523)$, $n=20471023$ ($k=11$) $\equiv 6 \pmod 7$ and thus it is composite ($20471023=479\times42737)$. With PFGW we arrived to $k=565000$ and all the $n's$ congruent to $6 \pmod 7$ are composite. According to Giovanni Resta's calculations in a post which has been canceled, there should be no probable prime congruent to 6 $\pmod 7$ upto k=800.000. The residue $6$ $\pmod 7$ occurs when either $m=6t+3$ and $k=3l+1$ or $m=6t+4$ and $k=3l+2$ with $k$ and $l$ some non-negative integers, but amazingly when it occurs the number is not prime. Can you find a counter-example or give a proof for the conjecture? Here a link to other interesting questions: [Is there a number of the form  $f(n)=7k+6=5p$ with prime  p?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666033/is-there-a-number-of-the-form-fn-7k6-5p-with-prime-p?noredirect=1&lq=1) and [Why do all residues occur in this similar sequence?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674050/why-do-all-residues-occur-in-this-similar-sequence)
For primes of this form see:
[The on-line Encyclopedia of integer sequences](https://oeis.org/A298613) 
The following vector contains all the exponents k<=366800 leading to a prime

$[2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 12, 19, 22, 36, 46, 51, 67, 79, 215, 359, 394, 451, 1323, 2131, 3336, 3371, 6231, 19179, 39699, 51456, 56238, 69660, 75894, 79798, 92020, 174968, 176006, 181015, 285019, 331259, 360787, 366770]$

Exponent $541456$ leads to another probable prime with residue 5 mod 7 and 325990 digits, but it need not be the next in increasing order.

Remark: we found five-in-a-row probable primes with res 5 mod 7. Probable primes with residue 5 are now twice frequent than expected.
Exponents of these primes seem to be NOT random at all. Another thing I noticed, i don't know if it has some importance: the exponents leading to a probable prime $215, 69660, 92020, 541456$ are multiples of $43$. I noticed that $\frac{215}{41}, \frac{69660}{41}, \frac{92020}{41}, \frac{541456}{41}$ all have a periodic decimal expansion equal to $\overline{24390}=29^3+1$. This is equivalent to say that when k is a multiple of 43 and the number $10^{m}(2^{k}−1)+2^{k-1}−1$ is prime, then k is of the form $41s+r$ where r is a number in the set (1,10,16,18,37). Is there some mathematical reason for that?

Comment: https://github.com/gnufinder/special-prime/issues

Comment: How can you give a bounty of $200$ when you only have $116$ reputation?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/294527/does-concatenating-mersenne-numbers-necessarily-lead-to-a-composite-number-in-th

Comment: It's worth to mention that if $n = (2^k-1)\cdot 10^m + 2^{k-1}-1$, then $2n+1=(2\cdot 10^m + 1)(2^k - 1)$. In particular, $n$ can never be a [Sophie Germain prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime).

Comment: Please reduce your editing of this post. It is not necessary to keep the search limit quite up to date in the post. If you want to have the current search limit on the page, post a comment (and delete it when you post the next). Updating the post once or twice a week is plenty enough.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2740494/can-concatenating-the-numbers-2n-and-2n1-lead-to-a-sophie-germain-prime-g

Comment: Passed k=360.000 no prime with res 6 mod 7 found

Comment: @Giovanni Resta Please, could you help us to find other primes of this type in the range k=[200.000...300.000]?

Comment: almost at 100 edits!

Comment: @qwr very helpfull comment!

Comment: @Peter on mersenne forum somebody pointed out to me that it is also surprising nine in a row primes 3 mod 7.

Comment: @EnzoCreti Considering that residue $0$ is impossible for ec-primes, the theoretical frequencies for residues $[1,2,3,4,5,6]$ are $[1/17,2/17,8/17,2/17,2/17,2/17]$ respective. Hence "nine 3's in a row" has probability about $1:884$ , whereas "five 9's" in a row has probability about $1:44371$, which is much less.

Comment: @EnzoCreti Is this true for all found ec-primes with residue $5$ mod $7$ ? If yes, this would be a nice additional conjecture.

Comment: Your new conjecture actually holds for the found primes. It might be possible to show the new conjecture, but I will have to work it out.

Comment: @Peter yes it was odd the last exponent.

Comment: The sum of the reciprocal of exponents converges? And at what value?

Comment: Curiously the sum of the reciprocals of exponents is close to $\pi^2/6$

Comment: 1/2+1/3+1/4+...+1/285019 is less than $\pi^2/6$ by about 0.001

Comment: @peter told me about this and i found it very interesting. I made this tool: https://solutionsti360.ca/MATH/pfgw/stats.php, so anybody can help computing. Simply download and run to participate. Just refresh the page to update stats.

Comment: @François Huppé I cannot install the tool on my office computer because I am not the admnistrator of the computer.

Comment: is it windows 10 or xp ?

Comment: @ François Huppé Windows 10...the problem is that I am not the administrator of the computer and so I cannot install the tool

Comment: @ François Huppé The server doesn't detect unique clients therefore when you fire more than one it will process the same work in all instances, on the same machine.
 Also there is a lot of idle time between server connection, would be wise to download more than one task. So said somebody on Mersenne forum

Comment: Yes, i updated the linux version, now it gets multiple jobs from the server, and also you can start multiple instance

Comment: i'll try to get the win 10 version to work tonight...

Comment: @François Huppé did you pass 200k?

Comment: @DanaJ would you like to join in this project? solutionsti360.ca/MATH/pfgw/stats.php,

Comment: @Peter Great news!!! During these holidays two new ec-primes found: 360787 and 366770!!!

Comment: @EnzoCreti Wow! I will analyze and doublecheck them! I think you checked with base $3$ , right ?

Comment: @Peter yes base 3

Comment: @Peter I bet residue 3?

Comment: @Peter I added the values in Oeis

Comment: I wanted to enter the new ec-chatroom, but apparently, it does not exist anymore. The first number has $217\ 216$ digits and residue $2$ mod $7$

Comment: @Peter so two-in a row mod 7?

Comment: And the second number has $220\ 818$ digits and residue $5$ mod $7$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82290/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).

Comment: @Especially Lime Giovanni Resta found another probable prime with exponent 541456. It is curious that $541456=700^2+51456$ where 51456 is an exponent leading to an ec prime!

Comment: @Peter@Especially Lime the first four ec primes are emirps. $31, 73, 157, 12763$. Moreover (13+2)/3=5 a prime. (37+2)/3=13 a prime. (751+2)/3=251 a prime and (36721+2)/3=12241 also a prime!

Comment: @peter 5,13 and 12241 are also part of a twin-pair!

Comment: The first four primes of this form are emirps $31, 73, 157, 12763$. $31^2+73^2+157^2+12763^2+1=162925109$ is a prime. And $13^2+37^2+751^2+36721^2+1=1348997381$ is also a prime of the form $157*k+1$.

Comment: $162925109^2+1=2*13272295571330941$ an even semiprime. $1348997381^2+1=2*909896966972429581$ an even semi-prime.

Comment: $162925109$ and $1348997381$ are both congruent to $2333$ mod 24.

Comment: $31^2+13^2-1=1129$ is a prime. $157^2+751^2-1=588649$ is a prime. $12763^2+36721^2-1=1511326009$ is a prime. All these primes end with digit 9.

Answer (score 9):

According to your list, a counter-example, if it exists, must have more than $60,000$ digits. So, a counterexample would be a quite gigantic prime.

Unfortunately, a proof of the conjecture will almost certainly be out of reach.

The search for a counter-example can be painful as well, it is well possible that the smallest is already too big for current algorithms for primality testing.

Comment: @EnzoCreti How did you get this list ? It shows that a counterexample must have more than $60\ 000$ digits. I think that the numbers of this form (no matter of the congruences) can have least prime factor very high. The probability that the least prime factor is very high is much higher than one might expect. A large "random" number has no prime factor less than $10^{20}$ with probability about $1.2$%. I do not think there is a special reason. Moreover, my list of candidates has become obsolete.

Comment: @EnzoCreti No, this is only known for arithmetic progressions of the form $an+b$ with coprime $a$ and $b$ (Dirichlet). The numbers here will behave like "random" numbers , hence we won't be able to rule out a large prime.

Comment: @Peter Every number is of the form $10^{m}(2^k-1)+2^{k-1}-1$, where $m$ is the number of decimal digits of $2^{k-1}$. As $\log_{2}10$ is irrational, the residues of $m$ and $k$ modulo 6, and hence the residues of $10^{m}$ and $2^{k-1}$ modulo 7, are independent. You can find out the distribution simply by tabulating the possible cases.

Comment: My observation just explains why different residues modulo 7 occur at different frequencies.

Comment: @Taneli Huuskonen And can you extimate in what percentage residue 6 mod 7 should occur?

Comment: Yes. The residue 3 occurs 4/9 of the time; the residues 2, 4, 5, and 6 occur 1/9 of the time each; and the residues 0 and 1 occur 1/18 of the time each. The residue 6 occurs exactly when either $m=6n+3$ and $k=3l+1$, or $m=6n+4$ and $k=3l+2$, for some nonnegative integers $n$ and $l$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72806/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-taneli-huuskonen).

Comment: @EnzoCreti Not really realistic. Sometimes, we only have a very small prime factor and a prime cofactor and sometimes the smallest prime factor has more than $15$ digits. This does not indicate hidden factors. So, it seems to be a pure coincidence that $6$ does not appear early. If factordb would allow concatenating numbers, that would be fine! But it seems that factordb does not support this yet. I have passed $120\ 000$ now without success.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73002/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).

Comment: Primes are of limited importance. They are used for cryptography, but there are better methods and the safety of the RSA is debatable. Such primes as the one you search are purely for curiousity. Nevertheless, many such primes were calculated. It is a bit sad that this kind of primes is not considered to be interesting by most of the people here. Of course, special primes, as the Mersenne primes, are more important because they answer important mathematical questions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73126/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2658464/is-frac-2716-915-680-41713-a-wagstaff-prime#comment5492093_2658464

Comment: @Peter Yes I have noticed.

Comment: For $k=32$, we have the factorization $$131\cdot 4463\cdot 21601\cdot 44623 \cdot 76213$$ This is a counterexample with residue $6$

Comment: For $k=586916$, we get a number of the form $7k+6$ divisible by $83339$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73471/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).

Comment: New project : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2666033/is-there-a-number-of-the-form-fn-7k6-5p-with-prime-p

Comment: @EnzoCreti Concerning the structure of the factors of those numbers, I search a prime factor of $f(530)$ and in a new project I search $f(n)$ of the form $7k+6$ such that $\frac{f(n)}{5}$ is prime which turns out to be tough as well.

Comment: @Peter ok I wait news from you.

Comment: @EnzoCreti To show that the smallest prime factor can be very large.

Comment: @Peter have you find a factor for f(530)?

Comment: @EnzoCreti No, seems that the smallest prime factor has more than $25$ , probably even more than $30$ digits. Of course, trial division does not work anymore to find such factors. The elliptic curve method is the key. With factordb , the concatenation for numbers works, if the numbers are concrete or depend linear on $n$ , for example $c(123,456)$ gives $123456$ and $c(n,n+2)$ correctly concatenates $n$ and $n+2$. Strangely, $c(M(n+1),M(n))$ does NOT cancatenate $2^{n+1}-1$ and $2^n-1$ correctly, otherwise this would be the perfect way to search further primes.

Comment: For clarification, $M(n)=2^n-1$ , the $n-th$ Mersenne number is a valid syntax in factordb. I also tried "c(2^(n+1)-1,2^n-1)" , but without success either.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2668139/concatenation-with-factordb

Comment: My post have 870 views but only 13 votes...so I think that there is skepticism about that conjecture or nobody believes it has some importance...

Comment: @Peter between 10^5 and 2*10^5 there are about 2000 candidates (or even less)...if the probability of a random number to be prime is 1 out of 4200, perhaps it will be still difficult to find a prime?

Comment: @EnzoCreti The logarithm is roughly $n\cdot \ln(4)$ , hence the probability that a candidate is prime is about $1:\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(10^6)}\cdot \ln(4)\cdot n\approx 1:0.0563\cdot n$

Comment: A large number has no prime factor less than $x$ with probability about $\frac{e^{-\gamma}}{\ln(x)}$, if $x$ is large. The approximation is already good for $x=10^6$

Comment: Didn't continue, probably no factor below $10^{30}$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674050/why-do-all-residues-occur-in-this-similar-sequence

Comment: Most of the conjectures on primes hold good only in a certain interval.

Comment: I know that, I myself am astonished with Legendre's conjecture that there exists a prime between every square number and it is true and has been put in landau's problems.

Comment: @Peter Could we start towards k=300.000?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74066/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).

Comment: Enzo creti, your discovery is remarkable. I don't believe I am saying this, but I think you should patent your discoveries before uploading them.

Comment: I have asked my friends to siphon some computer power from cyber cafes to help you calculate.

Comment: If possible could you take me in your chat room?

Comment: @VishaalSelvaraj A nice observation, but I don't think that is considered to be of great importance. Otherwise we would already have found helpers. r.e.s was a helper, but quit at $10^5$, now we are only two despite of 1k+ views. And without some luck or more helpers, we won't be able to decide the conjecture.

Comment: @Peter this morning I arrived at 248.000, the search has slowed down. I was hoping that on Saturday morning we would have arrived at k=300.000 but now I think that this is not the case...

Comment: @Vishaal Selvaraj you told me about a library...you said that it is necessary high power of the computer. How much do you believe?

Comment: 1.8 GHz give or take, but 4 GB RAM IS recommended

Comment: Actually the library uses custom data types with user defined precision..

Comment: @EnzoCreti It is not a matter of space, it is a matter of computational power and of parallelization.

Comment: @Vishaal Selvaraj Ok thank you very much, I have half a mind to buy a new computer (mine at home is broken I'm using the computer office). So I could help also Peter...

Comment: @Peter f(n)/5 conjecture is another good question...

Comment: No , it is a matter of memory space too since, the data types are 100~200 bytes in size and running operations on them requires more ram.

Comment: @EnzoCreti I know no primes of the forms given in this question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2374537/are-there-prime-numbers-cn-or-rcn?rq=1

Comment: @EnzoCreti Great!

Comment: @EnzoCreti You passed the $150k$-digit-mark. The largest known prime is only roughly $150$ times larger than the numbers you now verify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74236/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).

Comment: PARI/GP is slow with modulo-calculations involving very large numbers. With a better software we could sieve out more factors with pollard-rho, p-1-method, etc. So, perhaps you are looking for a powerful program that can do this. Or, alternatively, you are content with the fact that counterexamples will be very rare, but likely exist. What I finally can make : Estimate the number of primes in very large ranges based on the weak candidates (no prime factor less than $100$)

Comment: Surprisingly, the expected number of primes in the ranges  $[10^k,10^{k+1}]$ for $k=3,4,5,6$ is about $5.4$. Whether this pattern continues ?

Comment: In fact , the pattern should continue. Since $\ln(f(n))\approx \ln(4^n)$ for large $k$, the expected number of primes in the range $[10^k,10^{k+1}]$ is approximately $5$, if we only consider that $2$ and $3$ can never be a prime factor. The special structure of the numbers seems to  slightly increase this number to about $5.4$. So, we probably have infinite many counter-examples.

Comment: You should at least present all primes upto $n=10^5$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74488/discussion-between-peter-and-enzo-creti).

Comment: @EnzoCreti When do you have your internet at home ?

Comment: @Peter today at 16.00

Comment: @Peter the sum of the reciprocals of the ec-primes is about $0.052408...$ Curiously $0.05240...$ is about equal to $\frac{360}{\sqrt{360*2^{17}}}$

Answer (score 2):

@peter told me about this and i found it very interesting.
I made this [tool](https://solutionsti360.ca/MATH/pfgw/stats.php), so anybody can help computing. Simply download and run to participate. Just refresh the page to update stats. 
With 30-40 person, getting to $n=10^7$ should not be to long.

Comment: How many people participated already ?

Comment: @DanaJ have you a routine for Sage whcih allows to test this conjecture?