# Is there a number of the form $f(n)=7k+6=5p$ with prime $p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Here :

[Numbers $n$ of the form $10^{m}(2^{k}−1)+2^{k-1}−1$, where $m$ is the number of decimal digits of $ 2^{k-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635516/numbers-n-of-the-form-10m2k%e2%88%9212k-1%e2%88%921-where-m-is-the-number-of?noredirect=1&lq=1)

the numbers $$f(n):=(2^n-1)\cdot 10^d+2^{n-1}-1$$ are introduced , where $d$ denotes the number of digits of $2^{n-1}-1$ in the decimal expansion. So, we simply concatenate two neighboured Mersenne-numbers, for example $f(10)=1023511$. I know no prime $f(n)$ of the form $7k+6$.

> I also did not find a number $f(n)$ yet which is of the form $7k+6=5p$ with a prime $p$, so a number $f(n)$ with $f(n)\equiv 6\mod 7$ and $\frac{f(n)}{5}$ is a prime number.

With PFGW, I passed $n=122\ 000$ without finding such a number. Does such a number exist ?

Comment: I believe that maybe there was a typo in your code, the first counterexample is $5\cdot 11=7\cdot 7+6$. I've deleted the comment below, this was a bad counterexaple.

Comment: @user243301 This is not the concatenation of two neigboured Mersenne-numbers as described in the question. Look at the linkes question to see which kind of numbers are considered here.

Comment: @Peter I wonder if these are all coincidences...???

Comment: @EnzoCreti Perhaps in this special case, it can be proven that there must be another divisor. At least , $f(190)$ has the prime factors $19$ and a relatively large prime cofactor. Maybe I find further examples.

Comment: @Peter I'm going to take a walk around Lugano's lake, perhaps fresh air of Switzerland, home of Euler and Bernoulli, will give me some hint...I think that a proof would be quite difficult to find...

Comment: $\frac{f(2062)}{29}$ is prime and has $1241$ digits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73771/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).

Comment: This shows that we have numbers having a very small prime factor and a very large prime cofactor. This does not rule out "hidden forced factors" , but it makes it less likely.

Comment: @Peter I don't know...humanity is far away from understanding the distribution and the patterns of primes...maybe a theory still to come will explain all these things one day...

Comment: I finished the search upto $10^5$ without success.

Comment: @Peter mistery is getting thicker

Comment: Someone call Andrew Wiles...perhaps he has a solution...

Comment: @Peter are that  numbers congruent to 6 (mod 7) also squarefree?

Comment: @Peter tomorrow I will do, for this month I have spent all my 50 questions.

Comment: @EnzoCreti Not necessary, $n=1981$ gives a number divisible by $25$ and congruent $6$ modulo $7$

Comment: @Peter Ok conjecture failed!

Comment: @EnzoCreti Surely, Andrew Wiles is a genius! But I don't think that he is able to solve such problems. Note that Goldbach's conjecture is still open, and we don't know whether $n^2+1$ produces infinite many primes. Until we cannot solve such problems, we cannot expect to be able to deal with the questions like this one. Of course, I cannot rule out a proof, but the usual approaches like algebraic or aurifeuillan factors don't seem to apply. Since I haven't found a factor of $f(530)$ yet, I don't think that we can solve it without computer-help.

Comment: @Peter Infact Erdos said that when it comes to primes, even a child could ask questions such that neither the most brilliant minds in the world could answer...

Comment: What about $f(7)=55=5(11)$?

Comment: @Steven gregory that is not a number of the required form.

Comment: @Peter I don't understand how you are able to check up to 150000 my conjecture in only few hours whereas for me with an even faster computer it takes days!

Comment: @EnzoCreti Presieving is the key! And here we only have to consider numbers being divisible by $5$, reducing the number of candidates to test with factor $4$.

Comment: And I did not reach 150k, only 100k. And for your conjecture, the range 100k to 140k took me very long as well.

Comment: @Peter we arrived to around 103229...tomorrow at 10.00/11.00 Greenwich mean time we should have finished!

Comment: @Peter I was wrong, the search is slower than I thought...this morning I just arrived to 153167...I think that it will take another day for finishing the job. The search has slowed down because numbers get bigger and bigger...

Comment: @EnzoCreti I told you that it will slow down linear to the magnitude of the numbers. Yes, if it finds a prime, it will display it. To be sure, you can check the pfgw-file in which probable primes are written automatically. It should be in the directory where pfgw is.

Comment: @Peter Where I found the pfgw-file? I only see the command line and the grey windows which don't display any prime

Comment: Anyway, if it doesn't display something with a probable $3-PRP$ (If this is still the standard base), it didn't have found a prime.

Comment: @Peter Yes I didnt find any 3-PRP and I checked also pfwg files...nothing...I will edit my post

Comment: At this stage, a candidate will be prime with probability $1:8\ 676$ and it will further decrease to $1:11\ 268$. Needless to say that it will get worse, if we continue. Perhaps, the special structure makes a prime somewhat more likely though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73936/discussion-between-enzo-creti-and-peter).