# Can concatenating the numbers $2^n$ and $2^n+1$ lead to a Sophie-Germain-prime greater then $89$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $n\ge 4$ be an integer and $d$ the number of digits in the decimal expansion of $2^n+1$. Then $$f(n)=2^n\cdot 10^d+2^n+1$$ is the number that emerges if $2^n$ and $2^n+1$ are concatenated.

A Sophie-Germain prime is a prime $p$ with the property that $2p+1$ is prime as well.

> Can $f(n)$ be a Sophie-Germain-prime ?

I neither found forced factors ( small factors, algebraic factors , etc ) nor an example of a prime $f(n)$ being a Sophie-Germain prime except the cases $n=1$ and $n=3$ , leading to the Sophie-Germain primes $23$ and $89$.

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry. I forgot to check in detail,as it looked OK. What can I do?

Comment: @Bernard I already edited it back.

Comment: Do you happen to be a computational enthusiast or do you know computational enthusiasts ? We still search a helper to find new "ec-primes".

Comment: Thanks! I deeply apologise again

Comment: It is possible to exclude a huge range of $n$'s from the possible solutions
$$2^n\cdot 10^d+2^n+1=2^{n+d}\cdot 5^d+2^n+1$$
but 
$$2^2 \equiv -1 \pmod{5} \Rightarrow 2^{2(2k+1)} \equiv -1 \pmod{5}$$
thus 
$$f(4k+2) \equiv 0 \pmod{5}$$

Comment: I confess I do not know much  about Sophie Germain primes. My domain is mainly commutative algebra.

Comment: @rtybase In fact, $n$ must be odd, otherwise $3|f(n)$

Comment: @Peter Do you have computational results already?

Comment: Yes, the exponents $n\le 34\ 000$ leading to a prime $f(n)$ are $$[1,3,19,27,35,47,55,61,73,139,243,247,593,1635,1871,5745,7155,7245,9935,13421,18963,33251]$$  but only $1$ and $3$ as mentioned lead to a sophie-germain prime.

Comment: @Bernard What I mean is that we search someone letting pfgw (a primality checking program) run to help us with the search of large "ec-primes"

Comment: I linked the question of Enzo Creti to show what I mean