# Does concatenating the perfect powers ever lead to a prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, perfect-powers

I search a prime number of the form $$4891625\cdots $$ emerging by concating the perfect powers $p>1$ upto some specific limit $L$ With $L=529$, we get a number splitting into a $31$ and a $48$ digit-prime, so we have no forced small factors. According to my calculation, such a prime must have more than $19\ 000$ digits.

> Does a prime of the desired form exist ?

Comment: a definite maybe

Comment: There shouldn't be an $8$ in your prime, it's a typo.

Comment: @LukasKofler I don't understand. Why should a prime not contain digit $8$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I only meant the first number you wrote: it should be $491625 \dots$.

Comment: @LukasKofler I concatenate the perfect powers, not only the perfect squares. $8$ is a cube, so it is written down as well.

Comment: You're right, my bad!

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I do not expect that it can be proven that no such prime exists, so the only chance seems to be to find a prime.

Comment: Apparently, such a prime must have even more than $26\ 000$ digits

Comment: I also tried finding a prime. My calculations are now at $53\ 868$ digits and still no prime result.

Comment: @pietfermat Apparently, you have a very powerful computer/software. I and Enzo Creti search for a special prime for a long time, it would be nice if you would join in the search. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635516/a-conjecture-about-numbers-of-the-form-10m2k%e2%88%9212k-1%e2%88%921-where-m-is