# Factorization of a $116$-digit number

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

> What is the prime factorization of this number : $$2510840694154672305534315769283066566440942177785613805158$$ $$3255420347077336152767157884641533283220471088892806902579$$ ?

If we concatenate the Mersenne-numbers $\ \ M(193)=2^{193}-1\ \ $ and $\ \ M(192)=2^{192}-1\ \ $ and divide by $5$, we get this $116$-digit composite number.

I tried to factor it with the $1.34$-version from yafu, but ecm did not give a result. The quadratic sieve is very time-consuming.

The smallest prime factor of this number probably has more than $40$ digits.

How can I factor this number ?

Comment: Related : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635516/a-conjecture-about-numbers-of-the-form-10m2k%e2%88%9212k-1%e2%88%921-where-m-is

Comment: It's 116 digits composite with ECM done, then I think GNFS will be much faster than Quadratic sieve. Download a copy of GGNFS, edit yafu.ini to indicate the location of GGNFS, run "tune()" command then you will be able to run NFS on your composite. Also, "-threads" option helps :-)

Comment: @didgogns I invite you both to join in the project of Enzo Creti and to run siqs for this number.

Comment: It's might be better to use [CADO-NFS](http://cado-nfs.gforge.inria.fr/). At any rate you'd be able to solve this problem within a day.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I factored this 116-digit composite, the factorization is
$$C116=179870387995451933124857321125705471410636663412965107437\times139591664983685893216072195834659800165004530288592786103967$$

On my laptop with i3-5005U using yafu 1.34 and GGNFS, the factorization took about 14 hours.

Comment: Thank you for your calculation ! (+1)

Comment: Thank you for the achievement!