# Is any ec-number larger than $73$ the sum of a square and a cube?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

An ec-number concatenates the Mersenne numbers $2^n-1$ and $2^{n-1}-1$ decimal (see also here [A conjecture about numbers of the form $10^{m}(2^{k}−1)+2^{k-1}−1$, where $m$ is the number of decimal digits of $ 2^{k-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635516/a-conjecture-about-numbers-of-the-form-10m2k%e2%88%9212k-1%e2%88%921-where-m-is?noredirect=1#comment6162080_2635516) for further details)

> Besides $31$ and $73$ , are there ec-primes $p$ (or at least ec-numbers) that can be written in the form $p=a^3+b^2$ with positive integers $a$ and $b$ ? I checked the ec-primes with MAGMA, but $ec(46)$ is still an unsolved case.