# Ec numbers congruent to 7 mod 1063

Tags: number-theory

[A conjecture about numbers of the form $10^{m}(2^{k}−1)+2^{k-1}−1$, where $m$ is the number of decimal digits of $ 2^{k-1}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2635516/a-conjecture-about-numbers-of-the-form-10m2k) ec numbers are introduced obtained by the concatenation of two consecutive Mersenne numbers (40952047 for example). Ec(7)=12763 and ec(8)=255127 are both congruent to 7 mod 1063. I did not find yet another example of ec(k) and ec(k+1) both congruent to 7 mod 1063. Is there any particolar mathematical reason, can be that ruled out or is it just coincidence?

Answer (score 1):

The numbers

$ec(289922)$ and $ec(289923)$ are both congruent to $7$ modulo $1063$

Comment: $k=2268439$ is the third solution

Comment: $289922=2*144961$. $144961$ is the concatenation of two squares 12^2 and 31^2.